# convert character into var name for subset

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to remove data frame columns by subsetting the dataframe with a list of varnames, but I am getting an error:

```
stones<-grep("^stat\\.mineBlock\\.minecraft\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*?stone[a-zA-Z0-9]*?", colnames(ingame), value=TRUE, ignore.case=T, perl=T)
stones<-lapply(stones, function(x) get(x))
out<-subset(out,select=-c(stones))
```

stones values after running line 1 above:

```
> stones
[1] "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.sandstone"        "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.stone"            "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.cobblestone"      "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.cobblestone_wall"
[5] "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.stone_slab"       "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.redstone_ore"     "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.stone_stairs"     "stat.mineBlock.minecraft.glowstone"
```

Error on line 3:

```
> out<-subset(out,select=-c(stones))
Error in -c(stones) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the unary operator `-` on character values is not allowed.

But you could use the logical negation of `%in%`

```
out[, !names(out) %in% stones]
```

You may even be able to use `!names(out) %in% stones` as the argument to `select` but I'm not certain due to a lack of reproducible example.  For example, this works:

```
subset(mtcars, select = !names(mtcars) %in% "mpg")
```

but it's usually much safer to go with `[` subsetting.